# Code runner runs javascript in terminal but does't work in otput

Tags: vscode-code-runner

Hi when I try to run javascript with code runner i get only:
"[Running] node "/home/lukasz/JavaScript/app.js"

[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.11 seconds"
without any actual output.

When I switch to run in terminal everything works fine. Any ideas how to fix it?

[[Run in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZilG1.png)][[Run in output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNS9e.png)]

I compared settings of execution map with other on osx which is working perfectly and can't see any difference.